# How to get number of segments in each shard of a document | elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way that we can get number of segments in each shard of a elasticsearch cluster ?

I did looked into _cat/segments?v but i am not really sure of the **generation** block , because i need to get the total number of segment of a index.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with the [Index stats API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html) with shard-level details

```
GET your_index/_stats?level=shards
```

You'll get:

```
  "indices": {
    "your_index": {
      "primaries": {
        ...
      },
      "total": {
        ...
      },
      "shards": {
        "0": [
          {
            ...
            "segments": {
              "count": 4,                            <--- here is your information
              "memory_in_bytes": 107085,
              "terms_memory_in_bytes": 78808,
              "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 1256,
              "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
              "norms_memory_in_bytes": 8256,
              "points_memory_in_bytes": 749,
              "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 18016,
              "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
              "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
              "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 216,
              "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
              "file_sizes": {}
            },
```

Alternatively, you can also use the [Index segments API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-segments.html):

```
GET your_index/_segments
```

You'll get:

```
  "indices": {
    "your_index": {
      "shards": {
        "0": [
          {
            "routing": {
              "state": "STARTED",
              "primary": true,
              "node": "8Gql5xv_T7C8oXtPsWb4pQ"
            },
            "num_committed_segments": 4,             <--- here is your information
            "num_search_segments": 4,
            "segments": {
              "_15x": {
                ...
```